# HTTP | Naming authority

Tags: http

Reading through the HTTP specification I came across the “naming authority” term in the section describing the *Host* request header field*. Here's the excerpt:

> The Host field value MUST represent the **naming authority** of the origin server or gateway given by the original URL.

What does it mean? Why did they not use the terms “name” or “domain”?
________
* [RFC 2616. Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (Page 128, 14.23 Host)

Comment: Well, for one thing, it's not always a domain name because it can include a port number.

Answer (score 0):

It uses terminology from RFC 2396 (which defined URIs at the time RFC 2616 was written).

Note: you may want to read http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-21.html instead, it's currently in "Last Call".